# How to delete an embeded link (content editor) in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, content-editor

I tried to embed a link in sharepoint online and as a test I tried to do with a link from you tube. I don t know what happened but now the URL of the site has changed and every time I try to edit page and to delete content editor with the embeded link I have the 404 not found error.

Could you please help me get the old URL back and to delete the embeded link?

Many thanks,

I tried embeding a link in sharepoint online using content editor and now the site shows the yt page

Comment: can you show us the code you used in content editor web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following below steps once:

1. Go to your SharePoint site page (or site pages library)
2. Find the URL of the site page from the address line of your browser
3. Append **?contents=1** to the end of the page URL and press `Enter`

   - Generally the complete URL should be in this format: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/SitePages/PageName.aspx?contents=1`
4. The list of web parts used on site page will appear like:

   [image]
5. Delete the content editor web part which is causing this problem:

   [image]